# Specifying tick marks on the axes via algebraic expressions involving radicals

Tags: pgfplots

I have two tick marks on the x-axis at

```
\begin{equation}
\pm \sqrt{\frac{1 + \sqrt{33}}{2}}
\end{equation}
```

and one tick mark on the y-axis at

```
\begin{equation}
\frac{1 + \sqrt{33}}{2}
\end{equation}
```

that I want drawn.  (I put `%` in front of the commands that I thought would work.  So, the code does compile.)  The tick marks indicate the two points of intersection of the standard parabola `$y=x^{2}$` and the circle centered at `(0, 1)` with radius 3.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=5in,axis equal image,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-3.5,xmax=3.5,samples=201,
    ymin=-3,ymax=13,
    restrict y to domain=-3:13,
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
%    extra x ticks={-\sqrt{(1 + \sqrt{33})/2},\sqrt{(1 + \sqrt{33})/2}},
%    extra y ticks={1 + \sqrt{33}},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[samples=201,domain=-3.5:3.5,blue] {x^2} node[anchor=west, pos=0.9,font=\footnotesize]{$y = x^{2}$};
\addplot[samples=201,domain=-3:3,blue] {1 + sqrt(9 - x^2)};
\addplot[samples=201,domain=-3:3,blue] {1 - sqrt(9 - x^2)};
%\draw [fill] ( sqrt( (1 + sqrt{33})/2), (1 + sqrt{33})/2 ) circle [radius=1.5pt];

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It work  fine with `\draw [fill] ( {sqrt( (1 + sqrt{33}))/2)}, {(1 + sqrt{33})/2} ) circle [radius=1.5pt];`.

Comment: @salim bou  I see that you added `{` and `}` about each number specifying the coordinates.  Thanks.

Comment: @salim bou  For other people reading this post, I am informing you that you misplaced a `}`.  The code that will draw a dot at one of the points of intersection is `\draw [fill] ( {sqrt( (1 + sqrt{33})/2)}, {(1 + sqrt{33})/2} ) circle [radius=1.5pt];`.

Answer (score 5):

Was the `\sqrt` in the `extra x ticks` a typo? `\sqrt` is a macro for *typesetting* a square root, not calculating, so that wouldn't be expected to work anyway.

It doesn't seem like using the proper syntax works either though, for the ticks. A workaround that is acceptable for the small number of ticks here is to use `\pgfmathsetmacro` to calculate the values and store the result in a macro. You can use these to draw the dots at the intersections as well.

For the `\draw`, you need a pair of braces around each coordinate if you want to use calculations directly, as salim bou says in a comment. The reason is that the parser when reading the coordinate looks for a closing parenthesis, and get confused by the parentheses in the calculation.

If you want to pretty-print the ticklabels you need to use `extra x tick labels`/`extra y tick labels` or `xticklabels`/`yticklabels`. I added this to the code, but commented out. To remove the ticklabels altogether, just add an empty list to those keys,  e.g. `xticklabels={}`.

(Actually, I don't really see why one would use `extra` ticks in this case though, so in the below code I used `xtick`/`ytick` and `xticklabels`/`yticklabels`, but that's just a personal preference.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\extraxtick}{sqrt((1 + sqrt(33))/2)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\extraytick}{(1 + sqrt(33))/2}
\begin{axis}[width=5in,axis equal image,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-3.5,xmax=3.5,samples=201,
    ymin=-3,ymax=13,
    restrict y to domain=-3:13,
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={-\extraxtick,\extraxtick},
    ytick={\extraytick},
    xticklabels={},
    yticklabels={},
    %xticklabels={$-\sqrt{\frac{1 + \sqrt{33}}{2}}$,$\sqrt{\frac{1 + \sqrt{33}}{2}}$},
    %yticklabels={$\frac{1 + \sqrt{33}}{2}$},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[samples=201,domain=-3.5:3.5,blue] {x^2} node[anchor=west, pos=0.9,font=\footnotesize]{$y = x^{2}$};
\addplot[samples=201,domain=-3:3,blue] {1 + sqrt(9 - x^2)};
\addplot[samples=201,domain=-3:3,blue] {1 - sqrt(9 - x^2)};
\draw [fill] (\extraxtick, \extraytick) circle [radius=1.5pt]
             (-\extraxtick, \extraytick) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yep, I just noticed that mistake.  I had a misplaced `}`.  The correct code that will draw a dot at one of the points of intersection is `\draw [fill] ( {sqrt( (1 + sqrt{33})/2)}, {(1 + sqrt{33})/2} ) circle [radius=1.5pt];`.   Maybe you want to add this to your code.  I think it would be better for other people reading this post not to be distracted with my mistake.

Comment: @user74973 Updated.

Comment: Very nice!  I have not seen a command like `\pgfmathsetmacro{\extraxtick}{sqrt((1 + sqrt(33))/2)}` before your post.  It seems like something analogous to a `newcommand` command.  Please tell me where to look to get familiar with using it in a `TikZ` environment.

Comment: Actually, there is one modification that I would like to make to the display that your code renders.  I don't want the approximate values of `-1.84` and `1.84` on the x-axis and `3.37` on the y-axis to be typeset.  I just want the tick marks to be drawn at these points on the axes.

Comment: @user74973 It is similiar to newcommand, but its purpose is to store the result of calculations. Not much more than that to it really, for all the functions available see TikZ's manual.

Comment: @user74973 `xticklabels={}` and similar for y.